# Play 2.3.x created module not found in Github

Tags: playframework

I have created my own module (for couchbase wrapper) followed by the steps mentioned here http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=410. Initially, created the module and tested with local file path and it works. Then i pushed the module to github repository  https://github.com/sivailango/sivailango.github.io

In my sample project, tried to load the module from github, my built.sbt is

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.smartcoders" % "play-java-couchbase_2.11" % "1.0"
)

resolvers += "PlayJavaCouch Wrapper" at "http://sivailango.github.io/releases/"
```

but it couldn't download this dependency, com.smartcoders#play-java-couchbase_2.11;1.0: not found is the error in my console. I have created the github pages using .io domain extension. I couldn't find where was the error? sivailango.github.io is my github page link.

Comment: @Steve Chaloner could you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change resolver to

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("PlayJavaCouch Wrapper", url("http://sivailango.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Thanks @Steve Chaloner